# Biot-Savart Integral on a curved path

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I am calculating the following Biot-Savart integral according to the suggestion of @Ulrich Neumann in a [previous post called Biot-Savart Integral:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258312/biot-savart-integral)

```
(*p[\[Theta]] represents the path to map the curved portion of the \
saddle coil*)

p[\[Theta]_] := {d/2 Cos[\[Pi]/3 - \[Theta]], 0, 
   d/2 Sin[\[Pi]/3 - \[Theta]]};

(*FP is the final point at which I want to calculate the field.*)

FP = {x, y, z};
R = FP - p[\[Theta]];

(*The unit vector from R*)
ar = R/Sqrt[R.R];
(*Bx, By,Bz*)
{Bx, By, Bz} = \[Mu]0/(4 \[Pi])*
  Integrate[
   Cross[D[p[\[Theta]], \[Theta]], ar]/(R.R), {\[Theta], 0, 
    2/3 \[Pi]}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

The formula implemented by the code is:

[image]

where the vector R connects the element of current to the final point:

[image]

(the \theta angle in figure is not the same present in the code)
If FP is for example the point of coordinates FP={0,h/2,0} (centre of the saddle coil), the code returns the solution quite fast. However, If I set FP={x,y,z} to find the magnetic field at a generic point of coordinates {x,y,z} it runs for several minutes (~>10) and then returns the following answer:

```
{(1/(4 \[Pi]))\[Mu]0 Integrate[(d y Sin[\[Pi]/6 + \[Theta]])/(
   2 (y^2 + (z - 1/2 d Cos[\[Pi]/6 + \[Theta]])^2 + (x - 
        1/2 d Sin[\[Pi]/6 + \[Theta]])^2)^(3/2)), {\[Theta], 0, (
    2 \[Pi])/3}, GenerateConditions -> False],....}
```

which makes me thinking that Mathematica performs the derivative D function but it is not doing the integral.
Is there a way in which I can perform the integral?
p.s.: The code runs very smoothly and produces the correct answer even for FP={x,y,z} for the case for which the path is a linear segment of the form d[s]:=(1-s)*A+s*B rather than acurved path p[[theta]] as reported above.

Comment: A few thoughts:  (1) It seems entirely plausible to me that there is just not a closed form for this integral, which is why Mathematica can't find one.  You could always use `NIntegrate` if numerical answers are OK.  (2) Mathematica might be able to find the answer if you integrate over the full circle rather than just an arc, since there are various integration techniques that can work over a full circle but not an arc.  (3)  Providing `Assumptions` about the parameters `d`, `x`, `y`, `z` may help;  by default, Mathematica will assume they're complex numbers...

Comment: ... (4)  Is it intentional that you're integrating along an open curve rather than a closed loop?  Using the Biot-Savart law for open curves is [problematic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/668606/magnetic-scalar-potential-of-a-straight-wire/668636#668636).

Comment: The path is on the surface of a cylinder (A saddle coil). So I am breaking it down over the contribution of the curved and linear paths. I was looking, possibly, for a general solution which depends on the actual geometry of the coil which is basically the radius and height of the corresponding cylinder.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the concept of a saddle coil, but from Googling I assume you mean something like [this?](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Simulation-of-Magnetic-Field-Topology-in-a-Coil-of-Samila/6d8066389726f1a25d861f389034f3fcd1eb8503/figure/0)  With a geometry as complicated as that, I suspect you're going to need numeric solutions.

Comment: Yeah, that is precisely the saddle coil shape. By symmetry what I think I need is only the curved integral. My goal if I can find the expression B={Bx,By,Bz} is to calculate the flux of the magnetic field through the surface portion of the cylinder represented from the saddle coil. I have calculated the field B at the centre of the coil at position {0,h/2,0} and used that value in the flux calculation. I think that already gives a close estimate but it is an overestimation I believe.

Comment: Related:  [Biot-Savart Law/Magnetostatics solution,](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60254/biot-savart-law-magnetostatics-solution/85488#85488) which discusses the case of a single circular loop.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that looks helpful.

Comment: I think the x coordinate in FP={x,y,z} is problematic. In the sense that Mathematica can symbolically calculate the integral for FP={0,y,0} and for FP={0,0,z} (returning a complicated expression) but it does not handle FP={x,0,0}...